# IntelliJ doesn't show python facet even though i installed python plugins - The code runs successfully on Mac terminal

Tags: python, intellij-idea, intellij-15

[image]I am executing a python code with boto3 and runs successfully in the mac terminal but when i try to run it on IntelliJ J i see errors.

Several posts say that i need a project interpreter and i tried the below

1. added a python plugin
2. added project interpreter
3. aws connectivity
4. ran code from terminal and it executes just fine

Screen shots:

[image]

Comment: I still have this problem with `intellij 2023.1.4 ultimate`

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue with python facet in a project that was setup for kotlin.  Not sure if this helps but this is what I did to get things working

- Verified the python SDK was setup without issues (no red line in Project Structure -> SDKs).
- Reinstalled the python plugin.
- Updated IntelliJ to latest version (I think 'Invalidate cache / Restart...' would have worked as well)
- Once I opened the project again I saw IntelliJ recognized that it was a python project and created a python facet.
- [may or may not be useful for your project] I also added python interpreter to my module under Project Structure -> Modules -> [my module].  So I now have both Kotlin and Python interpreters.

I'm sure you have probably resolved this by now but maybe helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade IntelliJ version, and then I started seeing Python Interpreter. I am now at 2022.1.3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).